# Solr warming query for filter cache

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

So I read this: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache

and specifically

> The filter cache stores the results of any filter queries ("fq"
>   parameters) that Solr is explicitly asked to execute. (Each filter is
>   executed and cached separately. When it's time to use them to limit
>   the number of results returned by a query, this is done using set
>   intersections.)

So my question is this. Lets say my app filters on a set of different formatsIDs.  If the format ids are numeric say 1,2,3,4,5.  And there are many permutations of those being sent in queries as fq parameters.

if I wrote a warming query like this...

```
...
<str name="fq">format:(1)+OR+format:(2)+OR+format:(3)+OR+format:(4)+OR+format:(5)</str>
...
```

Would that warm things up and help all my queries trying to filter by various permutations of those formats OR... only folks searching for that permutation?

Should I instead create 5 separate warming queries (1 for each format) to take advantage of "set intersection"?

Or will that query create the sets for each format?

Example queries

```
...fq=format:(1)+OR+format:(2)...
...fq=format:(1)+OR+format:(3)...
...fq=format:(2)+OR+format:(3)...
...fq=format:(2)+OR+format:(5)...
etc...
```

so none of those I believe will use the filter cache created by the warming query listed above.

Comment: it is looking like this is saying that it is cached by the FQ field... and therefore with this "OR" logic I would have to create the permutations and run a query on each permutation for warming or the result set will not be cached or able to be taken advantage of.

Answer (score 2):

See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq. It says:

> The document sets from each filter query are cached independently.
>   Thus, concerning the previous examples: use a single fq containing two
>   mandatory clauses if those clauses appear together often, and use two
>   separate fq params if they are relatively independent.

It is one cache entry per `fq` param specified in your query.

You are not doing set intersection with OR; you are doing set union. But if you were doing set intersection like:

```
fq=format:(1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5)
```

(assuming `format` is a multi-valued field here) and have different subsets of those 5 values like

```
fq=format:(1 AND 2)
fq=format:(3 AND 4 AND 5)
```

then issuing separate filter queries like:

```
fq=format:1&fq=format:2&fq=format:3&fq=format:4&fq=format:5
```

will help all the subset queries. Here you will have 5 entries in the filter cache and they are intersected for all the subsets.

Regarding permutations i.e. the order in which the values appear in the filter query, I believe it will use hashing for the `fq` param, so you are better off sorting the values first and then forming your filter query.

Comment: Very well expalined, but what then if I want to warmup Solr for set union queries as in the original question?

Comment: If it is the same set of values you are going to use for the filter query, then just sort your values and use like `fq=format:(1 OR 2 OR 3)`. This will create one entry in your filter cache for the union of those three values. Every subsequent query should also issue the values in the same sorted sequence.